# How to sort list of student records by categories in Python

Tags: python, list, nested, names

Suppose that I have nested list that looks like this

```py
# Student records
data_list=[ # person, subject, grade
   ["John", "Physics", 5], ["John", "PC", 7], ["John", "Math", 8], 
   ["Mary", "Physics", 6], ["Mary", "PC", 10], ["Mary", "Algebra", 7], 
   ["Helen", "Physics", 7], ["Helen","PC", 6], ["Helen", "Algebra", 8], 
   ["Helen", "Analysis", 10], ["Bill", "PC", 10], ["Bill", "Analysis", 6], 
   ["Bill", "Math", 8], ["Bill", "Biology", 6], ["Michael", "Analysis", 10]
]
```

How can I create a code that prints what subject did each student attend to? The code output should look like this:

```py
# Subjects taken by person
[["John", "Physics", "PC", "Math"],
["Mary", "Physics", "PC", "Algebra"],
...]
```

I would prefer a solution that uses only Python lists.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a dictionary to collect subjects per person:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

subjects = defaultdict(list)
for record in data_list: 
    subjects[record[0]].append(record[1])
```

```py
# subjects
defaultdict(list,
            {'John': ['Physics', 'PC', 'Math'],
             'Mary': ['Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra'],
             'Helen': ['Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra', 'Analysis'],
             'Bill': ['PC', 'Analysis', 'Math', 'Biology'],
             'Michael': ['Analysis']})
```

This can then be converted to a list of lists:

```py
subjects_list = [[x] + y for x, y in subjects.items()]
```

```py
# subjects_list
[['John', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Math'],
 ['Mary', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra'],
 ['Helen', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra', 'Analysis'],
 ['Bill', 'PC', 'Analysis', 'Math', 'Biology'],
 ['Michael', 'Analysis']]
```

**EDIT** As requested by the OP, here is a solution using only lists:

```py
subject_list = []  # output
persons = []       # track unique persons
for record in data_list:
    if record[0] not in persons:
        persons.append(record[0])           # Track new person
        subject_list.append([record[0]])    # Add new person to output
        subject_list[-1].append(record[1])  # Add subject for person
    else:
        subject_list[persons.index(record[0])].append(record[1])
```

```py
# subject_list
[['John', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Math'],
 ['Mary', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra'],
 ['Helen', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra', 'Analysis'],
 ['Bill', 'PC', 'Analysis', 'Math', 'Biology'],
 ['Michael', 'Analysis']]
```

**EDIT 2** You can generalise this approach to sort your `data_list` by any *index* (e.g. person, ...) filtering out a *category* (e.g. subject, grade, ...)

```py
def groupby(data, index, category):
    """Sort list of records by index and category
    """
    output = []
    indices = []
    for record in data:
        if record[index] not in indices:
            indices.append(record[index])
            output.append([record[index]])
            output[-1].append(record[category])
        else:
            output[indices.index(record[index])].append(record[category])
    return output
```

This will allow you to list subjects per person like this:

```py
# index 0 -> person
# category 1 -> subject
subject_list = groupby(data_list, 0, 1)
```

Or you could list grades per person like this:

```py
# index 0 -> person
# category 2 -> grade
grade_list = groupby(data_list, 0, 2)
```

```py
# grad_list
[['John', 5, 7, 8],
 ['Mary', 6, 10, 7],
 ['Helen', 7, 6, 8, 10],
 ['Bill', 10, 6, 8, 6],
 ['Michael', 10]]
```

You can then get the number of subjects taken per person or the average grade like this:

```py
import statistics

subjects_taken = [len(x) - 1 for x in subject_list]
average_grade = [statistics.mean(x[1:]) for x in grade_list]
```

Putting everything together gives you:

```py
persons = [x[0] for x in subject_list]
final_list = list(zip(persons, subjects_taken, average_grade))

# final_list
[('John', 3, 6.666666666666667),
 ('Mary', 3, 7.666666666666667),
 ('Helen', 4, 7.75),
 ('Bill', 4, 7.5),
 ('Michael', 1, 10)]
```

Comment: It needs the code to take data from the data_list only and use only lists

Comment: @Nontas The code does only use the data from data_list. I added a solution using only lists, although you really should take advantage of other Python container types, whenever you can.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ll try the dictionary sollution as well. The code i wrote was very similar to yours but in the subject list i was putting 0 instead of -1

Comment: How can I get a result of each name following the number of lessons and the total average? It should look like this [['John', 3, 6.67],.....]

Comment: @Nontas I doubt that you get the right outcome if you append subjects to `subject_list[0]` (the first found person) instead of `subject_list[-1]` (the last found person).

Comment: I am trying now to make the same code as the last part, but instead of names, I want it to be categorized by subject (to give how many people attended the subject and what is the average grade). It should look like this [["Physics", 3, 6.0], ....].How can I find the percentage of students who got a score >8.5 and how can I print the subject with the most students? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I am quite sure you can figure this out yourself. But maybe what you need is a more convenient data structure after all. You could look into the Pandas third-party library where you can store your student information in a so called data frame. It offers methods for regrouping and all kinds of statistics. (It would be nice by the way if you could except one of the given answers as I think they solve your initial problem).

Comment: Pandas did the work! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you could try:

```
def consolidate(data):
    # list of names from  data_list
    names = list(set([i[0] for i in data])) 
    consolidated = [] # empty list to get the sublists

    # Looping for each name
    for name in names:
        subList = [name] # sublist for each name
        for i in data: # loop for each item within data_list
            if i[0] == name: # if name is the same, append the subject
                subList.append(i[1])
        consolidated.append(subList) # append sublists in consolidated list
    return consolidated
```

Call function:

```
consolidate(data_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Mary', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra'], ['Helen', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Algebra', 'Analysis'],
['John', 'Physics', 'PC', 'Math'], ['Bill', 'PC', 'Analysis', 'Math', 'Biology'],
['Michael', 'Analysis']]
```